# Ignoring LATEX special characters

Tags: characters

I have to add in a Latex document a page with the code from program I use for the report. However, when I simply copy and paste the code into Latex, I get a ton of warnings. Is there a way to tell Latex to ignore all of the special characters in the code, just in this part of the report?

Comment: Packages like `listing`s or `minted` take care of that/

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `verbatim` environment:

```
\begin{verbatim}
The verbatim environment
  simply reproduces every
 character you input,
including all  s p a c e s!
\end{verbatim}
```

Sample taken from here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Verbatim_text

Similar environment with line breaking and a tiny font size using [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,basicstyle=\tiny]
This is a very long line that breaks and is tiny...
\end{lstlisting}
```

And like Johannes_B wrote, there are dedicated packages for displaying source code listings:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted

They allow line nubering, syntax coloring etc. Example using [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[frame=lines,linenos]{python}
def function():
    return
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The verbatim command works nice, but some parts of the text are not displayed, since the lines are sometimes too wide.

Comment: Ok. There are ways to fix that: break lines or change font size to smaller. I added an example to both break the lines and decrease the font size using `lstlisting`environment.